# site hosted locally loads from mobile devices but not computers

Tags: apache, http, server, apache2, wamp

I have a site hosted on wamp 2, I've set everything in httpd, forwarded port 8080 on my router, and set wamp to put the site online.

I can access the site from any device on the LAN and from any cellphone, on or off the network.  However, I can not access it from computers on other networks.  I am using the address http://[ipv4 address]:8080/index.php.  I've tried accessing it without the index.php as well.  I get a connection timeout error.  What could be the issue?

I tried posting this on serverfault and was told that was the wrong site, so I am trying here.  Not sure if this or superuser is the right place for the question, so I apologise if it doesn't belong here.

Note: this is just for hosting a class project for a week while the TA grades it, I know this is not a recommended way to host a real website.

Comment: Probably meant for one of the other StackExchange sites to be honest. However, it may sound like the port is not actually open to the outside on your router. Try this site http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and input your IP address you get from http://www.whatsmyip.org/

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If it works from a Mobile phone on 4G it should work from any other connection, mobile or not. Check that the Mobile was indeed off the local wifi, I think your forwarding rules don't work although you think they do.

Comment: I confirmed this by having somebody in another state try to access it on their computer and phone, and they had the same results as I did - it worked on their phone and not on their PC.

I was never able to resolve this issue.